# Unable to access Redux state in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to display the redux state into my react component.My root reducer looks this:

**index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import PostReducer from './PostsReducer';
import { reducer as formReducer} from 'redux-form';
import CategoriesReducer from './CategoriesReducer';
import CommentsReducer from './CommentsReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    posts: PostReducer,
    categories: CategoriesReducer,
    comments: CommentsReducer,
    form : formReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Now,I am facing issues in accessing my **comments** state.My CommentsReducer reducer is as shown below:

**CommentsReducer.js**

```
import { FETCH_COMMENTS } from '../actions/comment_action';

export default function(state={}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case FETCH_COMMENTS:
          return {comments: {...state.comments, ...action.payload.data}};

      default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

In my component,I am trying to get the **state** in my mapStateToProps method as follows:

```
function mapStateToProps({ posts, comments }, ownProps) {
    return {
      post: posts[ownProps.match.params.id],
      comment: comments[ownProps.match.params.id]};
}
```

Now, in my render function if I try to get the comments state as **{this.props.comments}** , I receive null.I mean it does not display anything.How do I proceed?

**EDIT 1:** Adding screenshot of the state:
[image: state]

**EDIT 2** Conditional rendering:

```
{
            (createStoreWithMiddleware.getState().comments) ?

              <div>
                  {this.props.comment}
              </div>
                                                  :
              <div>
                Null
              </div>

          }
```

**EDIT 3**: Comment.js file in the api server.

```
const defaultData = {
  "894tuq4ut84ut8v4t8wun89g": {
    id: '894tuq4ut84ut8v4t8wun89g',
    parentId: "8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd",
    timestamp: 1468166872634,
    body: 'Hi there! I am a COMMENT.',
    author: 'thingtwo',
    voteScore: 6,
    deleted: false,
    parentDeleted: false
  },
  "8tu4bsun805n8un48ve89": {
    id: '8tu4bsun805n8un48ve89',
    parentId: "8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd",
    timestamp: 1469479767190,
    body: 'Comments. Are. Cool.',
    author: 'thingone',
    voteScore: -5,
    deleted: false,
    parentDeleted: false
  }
}
```

And my API endpoint is described as shown below:

```
GET /comments/:id
      USAGE:
        Get the details for a single comment
```

**EDIT 4** Screenshot of the output.
[image: devtools]

Comment: Did you connect your component to the redux store ?

Comment: @TimH yes,I did.I used this line of code `export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPost, deletePost, editPost, fetchComments })(PostDetail);`

Comment: ok this line should be fine. Could you please check if your mapStateToProps works properly? Maybe post some console.logs

Comment: @TimH I tried getting the state in my render method like this : `console.log(createStoreWithMiddleware.getState());` and it shows the displays the comments in the comments state there.I have added a screenshot above.Can you please have a look?

Comment: I guess its pretty much because the initial state comments in null in the redux store and until comments is available from FETCH_COMMENTS action

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I have tried rendering it if the comments state is true.I have added the code above in edit 2, can you please have a look at it and check if there's something wrong with that code?

Comment: Ok have you debug your code when you dispatch an action is it going to commentReducer state??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that you need to check

**First:** The below reducer is a comment reducer and `state.comments` is not defined so `...state.comments` will fail. So you need to update the initialState like `state = {comments: {}}`

```
import { FETCH_COMMENTS } from '../actions/comment_action';

export default function(state = {comments: {}}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case FETCH_COMMENTS:
          return {comments: {...state.comments, ...action.payload.data}};

      default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

**Second:** In `mapStateToProps` `function mapStateToProps({ posts, comments }, ownProps) {` posts and components are reducers and hence `posts[ownProps.match.params.id]` and `comments[ownProps.match.params.id]` is not what you want but

```
function mapStateToProps({ posts, comments }, ownProps) {
    return {
      post: Object.values(posts.posts).find(post => post.id ===ownProps.match.params.id),
      comment: Object.values(comments.comments).find(comment => comment.id ===ownProps.match.params.id};
}
```

Third: Now that comments are updated using fetchComments action, you should make a check for comment before using it in the component like

```
if(this.props.comment) {
    //do what you want with comment here
}
```

or if you are using it in JSX, use it like

```
{this.props.comment ? <div>{this.props.comment}</div>: null}
```

Comment: I am getting an error in my comment state if I change the mapStateToProps as you have mentioned.I get an error like this: `TypeError: Cannot read property '8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd' of undefined` . I have added my default comment object above in an edit from the server file. '8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd' is the id of thepost which that comment belongs to.Can you please have a look at it.Maybe I am making some mistake in getting the comment correctly from the post.

Comment: Did you change the initial state to `state = {posts: {}}` in postReducer as well

Comment: sorry,i forgot to make that change earlier.But now,even after adding the `state = {posts: {}}` and changing my mapStateToProps like this: `function mapStateToProps({ posts, comments }, ownProps) {
    return {
      post: posts.posts[ownProps.match.params.id],
      comment: comments.comments[ownProps.match.params.id]};
}' , it is not returning true in the condition of the render method.But I can see the comment in my redux devtools .I have pasted a screenshot above.

Comment: Also my condition looks like this: `{
            (this.props.comment) ?

              <div>
                  COMMENTS AVAILABLE
              </div>            :

              <div>
                NOT AVAILABLE
              </div>
          }`

Comment: Do you get `ownProps.match.params.id` in mapStateToProps function. As I see, you key to comments in not `ownProps.match.params.id` , rather it seems to be an array of object

Comment: Check the updated answer, I changed the part of mapStateToProps

Comment: I get this error `TypeError: posts.posts.find is not a function`

Comment: Is your comments object an array or an object, can you check it, also the response that you get from FETCH_COMMENTS, is it an array of object, because it sure seems like it

Comment: Or I guess instead of object with keys `894tuq4ut84ut8v4t8wun89g` , you are getting it with `0`, `1` , Please can you make sure of that and accordingly use your mapStateToProps function

Comment: You are correct.The comments are in the form of `0`,`1` and the `parent_id` of the comment is `894tuq4ut84ut8v4t8wun89g`.Sorry,i forgot to mention that earlier.So,how do I change the `mapStateToProps` function?

Comment: It works perfectly now.Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Glad it could helped you finally :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have used "comment" in your mapStateToProps.

You can access it using {this.props.comment} and not {this.props.comments}

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import connect method from react-redux then use mapStateToProps into connect method like:

```
      import { connect } from 'react-redux';
      class ComponentName extends Component {
      }
      function mapStateToProps({ posts, comments }, ownProps) {
        return {
            post: posts[ownProps.match.params.id],
            comment: comments[ownProps.match.params.id]};
      }  
      export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentName);
```

Comment: I have already followed the above steps.Still its not working.

Comment: Are you trying with this.props.comments?? Check the variable name.
you can access it by this.props.comment.